JQueryGridView not displaying data on Page_Load, but does on button click after the page loads
I built a new page using my company's JQueryGridView class that extends the base GridView class. The grid needs to display data when the page loads, but this isn't happening for a reason I suspect is related to the timing of the DataBind() and the JQueryGridView actually being built. We are using ASP .NET.
We use this JQueryGridView several places in our system. I partnered with a senior dev to make sure everything is set up correctly and it is. Based on the grid not displaying data our hypothesis is that the DataBind is happening before the JQueryGridView is finished initializing.
At first I had a call to the method that sets the Data Source and Binds the data in page_load. When the grid didn't display data I tried putting the bind data method call in page_prerender, page_init, and page_render, but every time the grid doesn't display the data.
The reason I think it's an issue with order of operations is I added a button to the page. When clicked this button simply calls the bind data method I tried calling in the page methods above. The button click works as expected and the Grid displays data as expected.

Without code we are unable to help you.

try once: $(document).ready(function(){ $('<either button id like #abc or class like .abc>').trigger('click');});

Thank you for responding, but it's difficult to share code from this because project hits a bunch of files.
I discovered the reason the JQueryGridView doesn't have data on Page Load is because the WebMethod to actually bind data to the JQueryGrid is not firing.  What's odd is this WebMethod does fire when clicking the button after the grid loads with no data.
I've been stepping through the code hoping to find a difference between the initial PageLoad and hitting that button, but I've come up empty. At this point I'm not even sure where to look.

you need to provide function code which is called on button click as well as your button and grid view HTML , so that at least we can understand what's going on?
